# App Engine - Too many open instances

Tags: java, google-app-engine, scheduler, instances

My app is running on App engine Java SDK, and since this morning I noticed that open instances are not handling new requests, and instead, new Frontent instances are being started.
So now i have about 250 open instances (a lot more than usual).
Also, the instances are running on version 1.9.5.

Please advice!

Comment: I'm seeing this too! Since this morning - we [greatly] ran over our daily budget in a few hours

Comment: please star this bug: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10894&sort=-opened&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log%20Opened

Comment: Having the same problem. Each request starts a new instance. Ran out f budget right now

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue has been fixed by Google at 2014-05-09 10:15 (US Pacific Time).
See [Google App Engine Downtime Notify](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine-downtime-notify/VmH7s-Eeyso/mgoxt1dMdFgJ)

How we fixed the issue temporarily:
Disable and re-enable the application inside the Application Settings. After doing this everything went back to normal. Since then we only saw instances spawning with the version 1.9.4. In our case a lot of instances spawned again after 45 minutes.

To make sure you won't get billed choose a maximum of Idle Instances inside the Application Settings. We changed the maximum to 4 idle instances. In this case a lot of instances still stick around, but you don't get billed.

Our App Engine instances graph:
[image: App Engine instances graph]

Comment: Strange thing: for my app, although there are over 350 instances started, the Billed line is normal. (2-3 instances billed) - maybe this is because we already had a maxi number of idle instances set. Also, all my instances are now running on v 1.9.4

Comment: After you disabled/re-enabled the app, the instance scheduler worked fine ? Did it stopped creating instances for almost every new request ?

Comment: We just did the same & I updated the answer. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3):

A workaround is:
"Disable and re-enable the application inside the Application Settings"
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10893#c3