# Frontend Instance Hours suddenly increase

Tags: google-app-engine

I have been using GAE App for 1 year and every day it cost me less than 1 usd for Frontend Instance Hours. However, today it suddenly increases to 10 usd. I do not do anything and traffic to the app is not increasing. Is Google changing the way to calculate the cost? 
Any suggestion for me? Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about what Google charges for one of their services. Contact Google customer support. This site is for programming questions.

Comment: It's not, Google app engine is currently spawning new instances for no reason like crazy, so everyone with this issue is suddenly being charged for lots of instance hours that are useless (no traffic). Same as This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559459/suddenly-huge-number-of-instances

Comment: Its still not a programming question. Have a look in the appengine group and you will see other people having the same issue. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/tlQPHCvP-14

Comment: But officially, Google is monitoring Stack Overflow, not google-appengine group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/Z6XN_64cA7w. And Stack Overflow is not just about programming, also about setting up environments, so if there's a question about auto-scaling and how to avoid having too many instances spawned, I think it's a fair question

Comment: A temporary workaround can be found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23558319/app-engine-too-many-open-instances/

Comment: For those saying "off-topic", you might need to blame Google for off-loading their customer support to "community support" by saying "ask development questions" at stack overflow as described here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/community

Answer (score 4):

The team is already working on it.

You can monitor the issue from here:
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10893

and from the GAE downtime-notify group:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-downtime-notify/VmH7s-Eeyso