# Google App Engine instances have big spike despite normal traffic

Tags: java, google-app-engine

For the past few months my app engine app has run with 2 instances no problem. Occasionally I have upped this to 4 or 5 to account for heavy usage.

Then all of a sudden the number of instances shot up yesterday, reaching 250 before I maxed out my $25/day maximum budget and for the next 6 hours seved 503. Then it magically started serving again.

It is now running fine again with 2 instances.
Unfortunately the outage came while I was fast asleep in NZ and I only noticed the unusual behavior on the instance chart this morning.

[image: Google App Engine instances chart]

There have been NO traffic spikes in the last 24 hours. And there did not appear to be anything unusual in the logs that would have caused a spike to 250 instances.

At the time the instances started rising (-20hr on the chart) I did deploy an "alpha" version of my app, which FAILED to complete. I rolled it back, then redeployed and it worked fine the 2nd time. Could something to do with the failed deployment have caused this massive spike?

Any other ideas as to what I can do to work out what went wrong?

I have been using GAE for over 2 years and never had anything like this occur. It is quite worrying!

Comment: The same thing happened to our app, it was an issue on App Engine's side apparently: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine-downtime-notify/VmH7s-Eeyso/mgoxt1dMdFgJ

Comment: possible duplicate of [Frontend Instance Hours suddenly increase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561788/frontend-instance-hours-suddenly-increase)

Comment: this looks pretty scary~  remember to check your billing and make sure they have adjusted the balance for you

Comment: Yes, they reset the billing... that's why it MAGICALLY started working again! But as I said my sight was down for over 6 hours after exceeding its $25/day quota!! Perhaps I should up my daily quota to something like $1000/day to ensure something like this doesn't affect me again (but still avoid waking up and finding myself bankrupt because some error on my part caused increased server load??)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im adding this as an answer as many people don't read the comments on the question.

The same thing happened to our app, it was an issue on App Engine's side apparently:

[https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine-downtime-notify/VmH7s-Eeyso/mgoxt1dMdFg](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine-downtime-notify/VmH7s-Eeyso/mgoxt1dMdFgJ)